# How to say "development and support" in Chinese

Tags: translation

As an example I want to translate "electronic document workflow system **development and support**"

Translation word by word: 'development' is 发展 and 'support' is 支援

But googling of 发展和支援 does not give any results at all that could mean the word pair is wrong. Can anyone prove/disapprove my idea

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**开发与技术支持**

**开发** is development as in *software development*.

**技术支持** means *technical support*.

**支持** by itself means support.

seems to be a common enough paring, here's two examples:

[image: 1]

[image: 2]

I guess you could also just say **开发与支持** if you wanted to cut out the whole "technical" part.

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: I have apparently skipped the domain in which you wish to use the expression. In technical context, development is 开发 not 发展, the latter is economic or similar. So the expression is 开发与支援.

---

Use another conjuction that is more appropriate for formal written language: 与.

The phrase you are looking for is: 发展与支援. With double quotes (") this gives ~24.6k search results on Google.

Actually the 和 variant gives more results than the one I have quoted, but for the name of an institution, book title, or other formal usage 与 is more appropriate. In spoken language your version is OK, too. The translations for 'development' and 'support' are correct.

Comment: How did you conclude that 與 is more formal than 和？

Comment: “与”的书面语色彩比较明显，因此多用于书面语中，口语中用得比较少。“和”则在口语跟书面语中都使用。另外，在书名跟文章的题目中，“与”使用得要比“和”多些。以上供您参考。 http://www.gmw.cn/content/2008-06/25/content_796229.htm